# Symfony session is empty after login when using a custom DynamoDB session handler

Tags: php, symfony, session, amazon-dynamodb, aws-php-sdk

I'm pulling my hair out over this one.

I have implemented a Symfony session handler using DynamoDB and the AWS PHP SDK: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.html

The session handler appears to be working completely fine on my local machine, I can see the session is created correctly in Dynamo, then when I login a new session is created and the data is migrated to it as expected. All good here.

The problem is, when I push this up to my staging or production servers on AWS, something is going wrong when the session is migrated. I go to my login page and I can see the session has been created as expected, then when I login, a new session is created but the data is NOT migrated to it, causing it to dump me back to the login page.

I've spent the last two days digging around trying to work out where it's going wrong, but I can't figure it out.

I've tried every suggestion in this bug thread but none of them worked, so I'm assuming I may be dealing with a separate issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6417

I've also tried using the `pessimistic` `locking_strategy` which does not seem to make any difference.

The staging and production servers have the exact same config as my local setup, minus xDebug.

I've put the staging server into dev mode with debugging enabled to try and find the issue in the profiler but I can't see anything of interest in there, the requests are as follows:

- GET `domain.com/login` (session a)
- POST `domain.com/login_check` (session a)
- GET `domain.com` (session b)
- GET `domain.com/login` (session b)

The pattern above keeps on repeating.

Any direction on how to debug this would be appreciated, I'm not even sure where to look, especially seeing as I can't reproduce on my local machine with xDebug.

Comment: Have you discovered the solution or made any progress on this?

Comment: @DerickF - yep, if you are experiencing the same thing, update your jsonc extension to 1.3.3 or greater and it should be solved. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a problem with the PHP jsonc extension where `json_decode` was breaking if there were null bytes (a serialized protected method has null bytes). It has been fixed since version 1.3.3.

http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=jsonc&release=1.3.5